# react native function return value not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am using react native code but some how code not working. please let me check how i can fix. i am getting value from cache and trying to return & show value.

i tried lot some how code not working if someone has any idea please let me know

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { theme } from "../core/theme";

class Dashdata extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.getDataName = this.getDataName.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            displayname: ''
          };
    }
    getDataName = () => {
        const displayname = '';
            console.log('getting value from cachedd');
            const loginName =  AsyncStorage.getItem('@kidssafety:displayname')
            .then((result)=>{
              console.log(result);
              return (
                <Text>{result}</Text>
                )
            });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.header}>Welcome Data {this.getDataName()}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
      fontSize: 22,
      color: theme.colors.primary,
      fontWeight: "bold",
      paddingVertical: 14,
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: 100,
      width: '100%',
      textAlign: 'left'
    }
  });

export default memo(Dashdata);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncStorage returns a promise. So you have to wait until it resolves.

Use Async/await to fix your problem.

```
getDataName = async () => {
    const loginName = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@kidssafety:displayname')
    this.setState({
        displayname: loginName
    })
}
```

Now you can display your values inside render

```
<Text style={styles.header}>Welcome Data {this.state.displayname}</Text>
```

**Important**

Since you are using as `getDataName` as an arrow function, you don't have to bind it as

```
this.getDataName = this.getDataName.bind(this)
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: yes i made all changes but where we running getDataName function to set displayname value

Comment: @SandeepSingh Place in inside ```componentDidMount```

Comment: @SandeepSingh I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage.getItem` returns a promise and by the time it resolves and returns a value, your render would have moved to the next line. Ideally you should store the `result` to the state and use it when ready. Then your component will look like.

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { theme } from "../core/theme";

class Dashdata extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.getDataName = this.getDataName.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            displayname: '',
            result: '' // add result here
          };
    }
    getDataName = () => {
        const displayname = '';
            console.log('getting value from cachedd');
            const loginName =  AsyncStorage.getItem('@kidssafety:displayname')
            .then((result)=>{
              console.log(result);
              this.setState({result}) // set result to state 
            });
    }

    render(){
        const { result } = this.state
        return(
            <View>
                {!!result && (<Text style={styles.header}>Welcome Data {result})</Text>}
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
      fontSize: 22,
      color: theme.colors.primary,
      fontWeight: "bold",
      paddingVertical: 14,
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: 100,
      width: '100%',
      textAlign: 'left'
    }
  });

export default memo(Dashdata);
```